# Resize rich:modalpanel (version 3.x) programatically with javascript

Tags: javascript, resize, richfaces, panel, client-side

Does anyone know if it's possible and if so how to resize a richfaces modalpanel programatically with javascript when it's opened.
I want to add an expand icon in the controls part of the panel to expand the panel.

A reRender of the panel with new width and height set through a bean might be a way, but I would really like to do it on the client side.

Comment: Have you tried `resizeable="true"` of `rich:modalpanel` ?